# C,open_MPI, user-defined-struct type not passing correctly

Tags: c, struct

I've used MPI_TYPE_create_struct to define an MPI struct datatype. A structure with 1 int and 4 double. However, the last element(double) in my struct never passing correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mpi.h>

struct c{
  int index;
  double charge,x,y,z;
};    
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  int rank,p;
  int i,j;
  MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&p);

  MPI_Datatype old_type[2]={MPI_INT,MPI_DOUBLE};
  MPI_Datatype chargestruct;//create mpi data struct 
  int blocklens[2]={1,4};
  MPI_Aint disa[2];
  MPI_Aint span,lb;
  MPI_Type_get_extent(MPI_INT,&lb,&span); 
  disa[0]=0;
  disa[1]=span;
  MPI_Type_create_struct(2,blocklens,disa,old_type,&chargestruct);//the struct has MPI_TYPE chargestruct
  MPI_Type_commit(&chargestruct);

  struct c buff,charge;
  MPI_Status status;
  charge.z=1.0;
  int targetp,sourcep;
  targetp=(rank-1)<0?p-1:(rank-1);
  sourcep=(rank+1)==p?0:(rank+1);

  if(rank==0){
    MPI_Send(&charge,1,chargestruct,targetp,rank,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
  else{
    MPI_Recv(&buff,1,chargestruct,sourcep,sourcep,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
  }
  printf("%d %lf %lf\n",rank,charge.z,buff.z);
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

The last "z", I am always getting 0.0000 for this in the receiving buffer.
Anyone knows why?

Comment: After trying out different possibility, If I change struct definition to reverse order {double charge,x,y,z; int index}. and change MPI_TYPE_create_struct correspondingly. I could successfully send and recv. I think it's something about padding in struct, but I cannot tell exactly what it is. Can someone kindly explain.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is padding,int is 4 bytes, but in struct defined in the question. 4 bytes padding was added after the int. the disa[1] should be 8 rather 4(which returns by the MPi_TYPE_get_extent call). in this case, it cannot be properly handled by send and recv, since the beginning of each elements is not located correctly.
The easiest fix might be using MPI_get_address instead, which safely gave the beginning of the element.

```
MPI_Get_address(struct c*.charge,&disa[1])
MPI_Get_address(struct c*.index,&disa[0])
disa[1]-=disa[0]
```

this should gave the correct displacement, and much safer way to create MPI data type